# Extend Scratch Org's Expiration Date

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org

Is there a way to extend the life of a scratch org? Can I extend the expiration out further?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

No. You set this upon creation and have no option to extend it.

In reality, you really shouldn't need to as the scratch org isn't supposed to be a source of truth that tracks your changes. It's supposed to be somewhere you can develop in and test those changes. You should be using git/VCS or have a local version of the changes/config in your IDE.

You can simply create a new scratch org and populate it with the same changes to essentially have the same environment with the current org that will be expiring:

1. Use `sfdx force:source:pull` to make sure your local copy is
   up-to-date with any changes you made in that scratch org.
2. `sfdx force:org:create` a new scratch org
3. `sfdx force:source:push` all your work to continue development like
   before.

Answer (score 4):

No. You cannot extend the duration of an existing Scratch Org.

You will need to [create a new one](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_create.htm) and that you can have a Scratch Org available for maximum of 30 days.

Because [Scratch Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs.htm) are predominantly source-driven and are disposable, so as long as you have your source in a repository, you can create a new and move the source to the new org, and that should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000M3yrQAC

Please vote for the idea regarding extending scratch org life